# Get unrecognized styles from stylesheet in JS

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet

How can I get the actual text of a stylesheet using JS?

The cssRules property only returns those rules that it recognizes.

eg. I would like to change -webkit-border-radius to -moz-border-radius.
Or do some JS wizardry to any element who's style contains myTrigger:true; 
(Do NOT lecture me on principal.)

Cycling through document.stylesheet's cssRules returns the parsed text *minus* any unrecognized rules, whether I use cssText, the array of rules, or the default rules.

Is there any way to parse an included stylesheet and view/modify each of the rules as it was actually written?

Comment: Invalid input = unpredictable output...you don't want to be lectured on principal, but your violation of the rules is the root of your problem, it's *always* better to fix the actual problem than work around the symptoms...

Comment: If you hand it to the browser and say, "Here's my CSS", you're at its mercy. You could instead fetch it *directly* from the server with XMLHttpRequest, fix/munge it in Javascript, and then construct the new `<style>` element with the modified contents. You'd want to guard against a serious "flash of unstyled content" effect by (for example) keeping the body hidden until you're done.

Comment: Firebug has access to the stylesheet as written, so I suspect it is accessible somehow, though doing ownerNode.innerHTML did not get me anywhere

Comment: @samgoody - Firebug is doing a form of what these answers suggest, a plugin can do more than plain JavaScript as well, it has access to more :)

Comment: The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSUnknownRule) states that unknown rules must be listed when accessed through the DOM interface. Unfortunately, none of the browsers I know do this. So the only solution is direct access unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is to load the stylesheet directly with a JavaScript xmlhttprequest then parse the contents yourself. Then, after doing that, use the JavaScript to insert your modified styles into the head of the HTML document.

Messy, but it'll work.

Comment: Any ideas for when the stylesheets are on a different domain?